# package manager for use as normal user inside home direcotry

Tags: linux, debian, package-management

I need a package manager for GNU/Linux (preferably source based) to install packages in my home as unprivileged user on a Debian system (not sure if squeeze or wheezy).

What I tried:

- **Compiling it myself:** Gave up after installing twenty dependencies and encountering some problems that surpassed my GNU/Linux skills.
- **Gentoo-Prefix:** My first problem were two broken links in the bootstrap script, after fixing them, the bootstrap failed reproducably when attempting to install stage3.
- **Home Arch Install (HAI):** Didn't seem to work, maybe outdated.

Did anybody succeed installing gentoo prefix in the near past and knows how to do it or have an alternative to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

**EDIT:**

I just tried unpacking debian packages via `dpkg-deb -x` but this is worse than compiling it myself. When compiling it myself, I can at least link against other self compiled libraries, so debian packages aren't an option!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42583/22222) on [unix.se].

Comment: @terdon Thanks, I'll give it a try as soon as I have access to the computer again (tomorrow)! But I don't think this would work very well as soon as the packages get more, especially complex ones and ones with many dependencies.

Comment: I begin to get the impression that there is no portable packaging system with an option equivalent to a configure script's `--prefix=~` -- this is a shame, but I can see all sorts of reasons why it's a problem nobody (myself included!) wants to tackle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pkgsrc](http://www.pkgsrc.org) is a nice platform independent ( different UNIX and unixoid systems ) that works without root rights. My experience so far is that it is working much better than Gentoo Prefix.

Answer (score 3):

Gentoo prefix is working now! As it seems, gentoo prefix is still maintained, but I'm lucky the system I need it for is based on squeeze and not wheezy or Ubuntu>11.04, because they are not supported due to multiarch patches to their toolchains which makes it impossible to build vanilla gcc!